# Android:Handling my function under Power(Red) button programmatiacally

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to handle Android HTC device Red (power) button programatically to stop my operation. I want to stop running some of my operation when user presses REd button when user is in my screen. I know for other buttons like Back button i could use "keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK" event. But what is for Power(End) Red button? I'm not getting any keycode events for Red button when i'm in my application.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot override the `END_CALL` key event in an `Activity` or `View`.

Comment: Ok. Do we know when screen is going off mode? Do we get any notification or find whether screen is off or not?

Comment: There is a SCREEN_OFF broadcast Intent you can listen for.